# How Do I enter username and Password on a webpage?

Tags: vba, excel

Q1)How do I enter the password and username on this webpage"https://.com/1/19/login.esp" ?

I have written the code to access the webpage:

```
Sub login()
  Dim IE As Object

  Const navOpenInNewTab = &H800
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "https://esp"
End Sub
```

Q2) what createobject should I use to access google chrome?

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub login()
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim HTMLDoc As Object
  Dim objCollection As Object

  Const navOpenInNewTab = &H800
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "https://ogin.esp"

  Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: Loop

  Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

  With HTMLDoc
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("USERNAME").Value = "yyyy"
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("PASSWORD").Value = "xxxxx"
  End With


  Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementById("loginbutton")
  objCollection.Click

End Sub
```

This code works....

Answer (score 2):

To find items on a webpage to select through VBA, you need to step into the Developer tools on the webpage by pressing F12.

Once there, you can find the elements you want to call by "stepping into" the code on the page and selecting the items you wish VAB to select.

Here is how that is done:

[image: Click this to step into page code]

Then select the username box:

[image]

After selecting this box, the code in the developer box will be highlighted, telling you what the code is that is linked to the item you pressed.

Here is the now highlighted code for the username box:

[image]

We have three options to select the item on the page:

- IE.document.getElementById (find the ID= in the code, here id='USERNAME')
- IE.document.getElementsByName (find the Name= in the the code, here name='USERNAME')
- IE.document.getElementsByclassname (find the class= in the code. In this case, class='focus')

*Note: Try to use to use the ID first, then name, then class as only 1 element on the page will have that 1 ID, but multiple items can have the same name or class, or its guaranteed to work if you have the correct ID.

```
Dim IE As Object ' InternetExplorer.Application
Dim UserN As Object 'username field
Dim PW As Object 'password field
Dim LoginButton As Object 'Login button

'enter username and password in textboxes
Set UserN = IE.document.getElementByID("USERNAME")
'fill in first element named "username", assumed to be the login name field
UserN(0).Value = ""

Set PW = IE.document.getElementsByName("PASSWORD")
'fill in first element named "password", assumed to be the password field
PW(0).Value = ""
```

Then you need to find the botton on the page, and click it.
Here is some code for that:

```
'After entering in the user/pass, we need to click the button.
Dim objCollection As Object
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementById("loginbutton")
objCollection.Click
```

There is a ton more info out there and more code on how to properly use each selection method, so this is just the barebones to get you started.
Searching for 'VBA IE automation' will get you some good results to work with.

Comment: Hi Helms. Not sure if this part is correct. UserN(0).Value = "". getElementByID doesn't return a collection, just an object. An ID should be unique for the page by definition. See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: After executing the above code there is a compilation error: Object Variable or with block variable not set